# What's this symbol mean?

Tags: symbol

I know its probably been answered before, but I'm not really sure what to google to find the answer.

[image]

Comment: It's a mechanical outline drawing of an IC.

Comment: Probably OP wants to ask about the symbol marked in red rectangle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That looks like numerical data to me....  I'm talking about the stuff in the red box fyi

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Could be this one: http://www.gdandtbasics.com/maximum-material-condition/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It indicates position tolerance in inches and (mm).

More info on [this](http://www.draftingzone.com/shoppingzone/6-1.pdf) pdf.

[image]

As comments in the question and this answer point out, the "M" in a circle stand for "Maximum Material Condition", as in largest pin width or smallest hole.

[image]

Comment: Just found this doc too :) Well, you win.

Comment: The (M) is described a few pages later - it's the "maximum material condition".

Comment: @EugeneSh. - well, its the first result on google-fu.

Comment: @duskwuff - thanks, I'll add the info on the answer

Answer (score 0):

Which is a Drawing layout for the Machining, with the GD&T positioning tolerance
The position tolerance M symbol represents [Maximum material condition](http://extrudesign.com/maximum-material-condition/) If there is L symbol That represents [Least Material Condition](http://extrudesign.com/least-material-condition/).